# Is there a jQuery slider / slideshow plugin that employs css3 animations when they're available?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, css

My question is if there is a plugin, maybe not unlike [jQuery Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) that can handle and uses 3d transform/css3 transitions to handle the animations if they're available?

A good option I found is [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) (note: Flexslider does not work 100% with jQuery 1.7) because it scores well on compatibility with touch and scroll events. But I find that when you want to have a different animation it is not that extendible.

I need a [cover animation](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/cover.html) (I think the demo might be a bit broken though, slide needs to slide over from the right side to the left over the old slide) but I am really just interested in a jQuery plugin that employs css3 animations  where possible and is sort-off extendible.

It must have:

- CSS3 Transitions when possible, fallback for older browsers
- Flexible enough to bind next/prev into touch/scroll events
- Extendible / usable if it doesn't already have a ready made cover animation

Some plusses would be:

- Ready made integration for touch / scroll
- Navigation between slides
- Hooks for before/after an animation

Though those last items I can easily fabricate myself if needed, I just don't want to start on the transition logic if someone smarter than me already did that once and made it available...

To be clear; I need this to support mobile devices (iOS, Android) and transitions are currently the smoothest way to have any active content, when forced to be HW accelerated.

**The precise question has not been answered so it's still open and up for an answer**

I will award another bounty for an exact answer if anyone can provide it.

Comment: Not a plugin per se but this may be helpful: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/rotating-slideshow-jquery-css3/

Comment: you can use any Slider you want plus my CSS3 Animate plugin. Working demo here: http://www.alainbenoit.com/ , plugin here: http://www.alainbenoit.com/js/plugins/jquery.css3animate.js It replaces the jquery animate method with CSS3 animations when available

Comment: http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/ uses CSS3 animations

Answer (score 5):

Personally I've really enjoyed working with Slicebox

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/05/slicebox-3d-image-slider/

It has nice 3D transitions for capable browsers but falls back gracefully in other browsers.

Comment: I'll be giving you the bounty since this is a nice plugin and it has a demo that actually worked in IE7, which can't be said for some of the other suggestions. However since no one managed to really answer the question I'll be leaving that open.

Answer (score 2):

royalslider may work

or

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/27/beautiful-photo-stack-gallery-with-jquery-and-css3/

There are actually a bunch of nice examples/tutorials on the tympanus site.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but a good plugin nonetheless. +1

Answer (score 2):

If your example is cycle try Cycle2 is responsive support swippe and accept Css transition (see API transition)
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/
If you want a very simple slideshow try tcycle.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/tcycle/basic.php

Comment: I wasn't aware malsup had a new cycle version, thats good news I guess. However, it still doesn't seem like theres transition/css3 support, which was one of the main reasons I asked this question. I could be mistaken and it could be css3 transitions only work for mobile devices, however that would be weird, since chrome supports these as well.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://www.sequencejs.com/. Not sure if it exactly what you are looking for, but it uses CSS3 animations for the slides

Answer (score 0):

your question is not all that relevant; let me explain ...

there is a new javascript command called "requestAnimationFrame", which is basically the javascript equivalent of css3 transitions. it allows the browser to schedule the repaint events so it is nicely optimized. 
if available this is used by jquery under the hood already. that means it applies to *all* libraries that use the animate() command. so: don't worry, it's taken care of :)

note that you cannot really have a css transitions fallback with javascript animations. those two are quite different and thus you'll get all sorts of weird differences in behaviour. (it might be fine for very special cases, but you'll quickly find yourself in a dead end).

Comment: an additional note: don't get stuck to much on that "css3 transition" buzzword, requestAnimationFrame is equally awsome!

Comment: omg, i just dug into it a bit more and it seems requestAnimationFrame support was removed again from jQuery. i predict my answer will be correct again in ~ 1.5 years :) 

never mind though, i'm still quite sure you have to use either javascript, or css transitions. i tried combining them once, pulled my hair out, then went back to jquery.animate() (when requestAnimationFrame support was still in there).

Comment: On iOS and Androïd, CSS3 transitions are currently way smoother than jQuery animate. So you have to use both, and it's not so difficult for simple sliders and effects.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame has some obvious.... disadvantages, they're not really flaws but they require a different way of thinking which most are not really ready for.. So css3 all the way, especially for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cu3er.  Great animations.  Extensible via the API.  Fallback.  The works...

http://getcu3er.com/

(Not jQuery, per se, but Javascript, and will do what you need in your app, robustly and just as easily.)

Also: check out Photoswipe...which is jQuery, and can be tweaked without too much effort.  I've used it to create some interesting and responsive image galleries.  But a slider is part and parcel of its possible installs, too.

http://www.photoswipe.com/

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Isotope, it has the fallback integrated.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/animating.html